# Windows, runnig script with variable paramameter, for cycle

Tags: for-loop, command-line, batch-file, window

There is a list of text files that needs to be processed. Their names are

```
samples\file_1.txt
...
samples\file_100.txt
```

A script calls file test.exe with 2 parameters. The first and second parameters represent input and output file names, which change with the increment 1, and the parameter -t is fixed:

```
test.exe  \input\file_1.txt \output\file_1.txt -t
...
test.exe  \input\file_100.txt \output\file_100.txt -t
```

How to write a simplified version of the script, processing files one by one, using the for cycle?

I solved this problem using the Python script, but hope, there is a more common way...

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like homework to me. What have you tried so far? Did you read `help for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\samples\input"
md "..\output" 2>nul
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
test.exe "%%a" "..\output\%%a" -t
)
```